# PLSql variable between # symbol

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've seen a procedure where `#` is used with variable with WHERE and IN clause.

Eg

```
in (#partyid#)

where (#seqid#)
```

Please explain its use.

Comment: Smells like preparation for dynamic SQL, where e.g. `#seqid#` will be later replaced with something that is correct (as far as syntax is concerned). Because, the way it is now, it won't compile.

Comment: That's definitely invalid PL/SQL (or SQL for that matter)

Comment: This is also the format for using ColdFusion variables as values: `WHERE col1 = '#var_name#'`